# How to measure execution time of functions (in microseconds) using Racket?

Tags: racket, benchmarking, execution-time

I want to measure how long a *function*  would take to execute if I run it with `n` as parameter.

For example if I run the following in my DrRacket compiler:

```
(time(insertionSortInt testingSample ))
```

I get :

[image]

`insertionSortInt` is a sorting function which sorts a list of random integers. Nowhere in that function is there a print statements that prints its element as it sorts the list. However, when I run the `(time...` function, it shows some time calculations and prints the list (as you can see above).

I do not want to print the list, however, I want to see how long it would take if I were to run a function, `foo`, with `n` as a parameter (measured in microseconds).

Answer (score 1):

Racket's `time-apply` procedure should be able suppress printing the result for you. The time is put into the return values instead of printed to the output port. Read more here: [https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._time-apply%29%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._time-apply%29%29)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post
[How to get Racket to not print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063011/how-to-get-racket-to-not-print)
It should answer your question on how to not print for a specific statement.

Comment: This print may have been a side effect of using time? I do not know for sure

Comment: The post explains it quite well. The default language in Racket prints top level statements (REPL). To avoid this you can just add a (void) at the end of the statement in which you want to remove the prints.

Comment: You should always cite the reference as you have done.  In addition, you should post the summary of the solution here.  This is because the links may not always exist.

Answer (score 0):

Racket prints the list because you're talking to a REPL: a read eval *print* loop.  If you don't want the values of a form to be printed the way to avoid that is either not to return any values, or to return the special 'void' value which is not printed.

The printing of the values does not alter the timing, because it happens after the time has been computed.  See below for an implementation which shows you why this is.

So for instance:

```
(define (call/suppress f . args)
  (apply f args)
  (values))

(define-syntax-rule (suppress form ...)
  (call/suppress (thunk form ...)))
```

And now

```
> (suppress (time (make-list 1000000 #f)))
cpu time: 98 real time: 89 gc time: 79
```

If what you want is to *return* the three time values (which will then be printed) then you can do that:

```
(define (call/times f . args)
  (let-values ([(_ cpu real gc) (time-apply f args)])
    (values cpu real gc)))

(define-syntax-rule (times form ...)
  (call/times (thunk form ...)))
```

And now

```
> (times (make-list 1000000 #f))
```

All these times are in milliseconds: Racket does not have microsecond timers.  You can multiply by 1000 if you like but the last three digits will always be zero of course.

Finally here is a toy implementation of `time` which should convince you that the printing by the REPL does not alter the timing:

```
(define (call/printing-time f . args)
  (let-values ([(results cpu real gc) (time-apply f args)])
    (printf "cpu ~S real ~S gc ~S~%" cpu real gc)
    (apply values results)))

(define-syntax-rule (printing-time form ...)
  (call/printing-time (thunk form ...)))
```

As you can see the time is computed *before* the printing happens.  It's quite easy to check this, in fact, by running Racket from the command line and asking it to compute something which is hairy to print but (relatively) easy to compute.  For instance:

```
$ time racket -e '(time (expt (expt 10 10) (expt 10 6)))' >/tmp/x
16.64s user 0.69s system 93% cpu 18.518 total
$ head -1 /tmp/x
cpu time: 5624 real time: 6008 gc time: 202
```

So you can see that *computing* `(expt (expt 10 10) (expt 10 6))`, which is a number with 10,000,000 digits, took about 6 seconds, while *printing* it took about another 12 seconds.